# PrimeNG p-dataTable responsive breakpoint

Tags: angular, mean, primeng

I am curerntly using PrimeNG 4.2.0 for my MEAN app. 
Code snippet is below:

```
<div class="ui-g-12" *ngIf="orders">
  <p-dataTable
    [value]="orders"
    [responsive]="true"
    selectionMode="single" 
    [(selection)]="selectedOrder" 
    (onRowDblclick)="onRowSelect($event)"
    styleClass="ordersTable"
  >
    <p-column header="Date" [style]="{'width':'15%'}"> 
      <ng-template let-col let-order="rowData" pTemplate='body'>
        <span>{{order.orderDate | date:'shortDate'}}</span>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="orderNumber" header="ID" [style]="{'width':'15%'}" [filter]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="userId" header="Client ID" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column header="No. of Products" [style]="{'width':'12%'}">
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col let-order="rowData">
        <span>{{order.orderDetails.length}}</span>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    ...
    <p-footer *ngIf="orders">
      Total orders: {{orders.length}} 
    </p-footer>
  </p-dataTable>
</div> <!--Orders DATA Ends-->
```

Is there a way to set the breakpoint for the DataTable's responsiveness? Because the current result on width: 667 (iPhone 6 landscape mode) is horrendous.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of minutes messing around with Chrome Dev Tools's Elements tag, I was able to solve my problem.

PrimeNG datatable responsiveness is implemented deep in side of tbody > tr > td row where the @media query presents. To ensure the responsiveness to show on mypreferred screensize (change the breakpoint per say), I had to add this to my root styles.css

```
    @media (max-width: 1365px) /* I want the datatable to be stacked at at least iPad Pro portrait mode, this depends on your data */ 
{
    /* Data in responsive mode */
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data > tr > td {
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: left;
        border: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }


    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-widget-content {
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }

    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data.ui-widget-content {
        border: 0;
    }

    /*Hide the headers in responsive mode*/
    .ui-datatable-reflow thead th {
        display: none !important;
    }

    /*Display the headers inline with the data in responsive mode */
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
        padding: .4em;
        min-width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a very similar need but using Table component (p-table), and I was able to workaround it by only setting this property: *[autoLayout]="true"*

Example:
Previous code:

```
<p-table [value]="averbacaoList" selectionMode="single" [rows]="5"  [paginator]="true" [alwaysShowPaginator]="false"
>
```

Actual code with new property set:

```
<p-table [value]="averbacaoList" selectionMode="single" [rows]="5"  [paginator]="true" [alwaysShowPaginator]="false"
  [autoLayout]="true"
>
```

Comment: By using autoLayout, all the columns get the max width of their content, which creates a horizontal scrollbar on mobile devices because the table becomes bigger than the screen. I prefer Chau Tran's approach.

Answer (score 1):

Chau Tran's answer is valid for the old DataTable from PrimeNG, but it doesn't work for their recent Table component. Based on his approach, I found the necessary CSS in table.css from PrimeNG and just copied it for a bigger screen size in my root styles.scss (tested in PrimeNG 8):

```
@media (max-width: 1365px) /* I want the datatable to be stacked at at least iPad Pro portrait mode, this depends on your data */
{
  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-thead > tr > th,
  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tfoot > tr > td {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .ui-table-responsive colgroup {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tbody > tr > td {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    border: 0 none;
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }

  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tbody > tr > td .ui-column-title {
    padding: .4em;
    min-width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```